# Schedule a task after a specific interval in Java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I've got a class

```
class A {
     int a=0;
     public int getVal() {
         return a;
     }
}
```

and I've to execute the function  getVal periodically. How do I do it from another class b?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm writing a simple program in Java and not using Swing. So,, is there anyway to call getVal() without putting it inside run() or using the run() at all? Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Old Way**

[`java.util.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

---

**New (and preferred) Way**

[`java.util.concurrent.Executors`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

---

**Implementation**

More specifically, use the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) class.

Answer (score 3):

Various potential problems with `java.util.Timer` are listed in section 6.2.5 of "Java Concurrency in Practice." For example:

- `Timer` behaves poorly if a `TimerTask` takes too long to run.
- `Timer` behaves poorly if a `TimerTask` throws an unchecked exception.

The authors of that book concluded that "there is little reason to use `Timer` in Java 5.0 or later."

Instead, they recommend using a `ScheduledExecutorService`. You can construct one either via the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` constructor or via the `newScheduledThreadPool` factory methods in `Executors`. The later option is better.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Timer class.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: It always worked well for me, but there's also the more "modern" API ScheduledExecutorService and ScheduledFuture, which does the trick as well.

Answer (score 1):

Simply just give a look on Threads in java. you can make this class runnable, and execute the function periodically, and the delay can be generated using the sleep() function. Otherwise you can make the calling function runnable.